# Use TypeScript to enforce parameter names for purposes of Dependency Injection

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

I have a library which incorporates DI. It simply uses a parameter name, and in a particular case, the first argument to a function must have the name "foo", something like this:

```
t.zoom = function(foo: string, bar: Object, baz?: Function){

};
```

is there a way to use TypeScript to enforce that the first parameter name to `zoom` is `"foo"`?

In other words, this shouldn't compile:

```
    t.zoom = function(bar: string, baz: Object){

    };
```

and this shouldn't either:

```
    t.zoom = <any> function(bar, foo){

    };
```

More generally, is there a way to enforce parameter names with TypeScript?

Comment: Name is not a part of a signature. Either way, it's an odd decision. I'd say that you should reconsider this design solution.

Comment: you mean throw DI out the window? :) I think DI is a nice feature for many reasons, as long as it is not overcomplicated.

Comment: I updated the question to be a little more specific with type info

Comment: "you mean throw DI out the window?" --- I don't. But the problem with this particular design solution is that - how would it work for a production code that mangles identifiers?

Comment: I have a solution for that already, it's even better than how AngularJS does it

Comment: the pattern I just mentioned looks like this: https://gist.github.com/ORESoftware/3c2314009b2fb4725d30ce39ec12a5e1

Comment: but my library is a test library, and it's not very likely that minification will be used for test code, although I am prepared for it.

Comment: Custom lint rule? https://palantir.github.io/tslint/develop/custom-rules/

Comment: lint rule is a great idea, there is tslint, or eslint, maybe you can add an answer